# Terrain Generation fills up entire screen with a weird pattern instead of generating terrain

Tags: mit-scratch

[Code used for terrain generation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvjXT.png)

[How it appears on testing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtRxv.png)

So, I tried to replicate Minecraft and I started with terrain generation. **I tried using Perlin noise, but instead of generating Minecraft-like terrain, it just makes a weird pattern.**

Comment: There is no Perlin noise in your code. `switch costume to (pick random (1) to (diff tiles))` is just value noise.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thats not a pattern, but just random pixels. Second, Perlin noise is not just a random number, its a complex algorithm. Read more here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise
Overall, your code does exactly what you told it to do.